# Obtain Form, Control and Property Data from a Different Database

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to figure out how to get form, control and property data from an Access form that is not in the Access database from where I start the code.  I have figured out how to get the data from within the database but I cant figure out how to get the data from a form outside of the database.

I thought that if I were to set the foreign database to the current database, my code would work.  However, after executing "For Each frm In appAccess.Forms," the cursor goes to "End Sub."

I tried to work with containers and I was able to return the form name but I wasn't able to figure out how to loop through the controls and properties collections.

Below is the code associated with my first thought.  My end objective is to be able to save form data in a different database.  Is there a small error with my code or is there a different method I should use to get the data?

```
Sub GetControlForm()
Dim strPath As String
Dim frm As Form
Dim ctrl As Control
Dim prop As Property

Dim appAccess As New Access.Application
Dim dbs As DAO.Database

strPath = "C:\Users\Tyrone\Desktop\Test14.accdb"
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase (strPath)

'MsgBox appAccess.CurrentDb.Name
For Each frm In appAccess.Forms
    MsgBox frm.Name

    For Each ctrl In frm.Controls
        MsgBox ctrl.Name
        MsgBox ctrl.ControlType.TypeName
        MsgBox TypeName(ctrl)

        For Each prop In ctrl.Properties
             If prop.Name = "RowSource" Then
                MsgBox "stop it"
             End If
            If (TypeName(ctrl) = "ComboBox" Or TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox") And (prop.Name = "RowSource" Or prop.Name = "ControlSource") Then
                MsgBox prop.Value
            End If
        Next prop
    Next ctrl
Next frm

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you looked at the difference between `CodeDB` and `CurrentDB`, and `CodeProject` and `CurrentProject`? If your code is in an Access add-in, it can enumerate the items in itself (the codeDB) or the current database.

Comment: I hadn't considered using CodeDB and CodeProject.  As of now, I want to avoid having to create an add-in.  However, that is good information for further research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your `For Each` has nothing to loop through is that the forms in the remote database are not open. Per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213489(v=office.12).aspx):

> "The properties of the **Forms** collection in Visual Basic refer to forms
>   that are currently open."

Try this:

```
Sub GetControlForm()

    Dim strPath As String
    Dim obj As AccessObject
    Dim frm As Form
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim prop As Property

    Dim appAccess As New Access.Application
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database

    strPath = "C:\Users\Tyrone\Desktop\Test14.accdb"
    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase (strPath)

    'MsgBox appAccess.CurrentDb.Name
    For Each obj In appAccess.CurrentProject.AllForms

        appAccess.DoCmd.OpenForm obj.Name
        Set frm = appAccess.Forms(obj.Name)

        MsgBox frm.Name

        For Each ctrl In frm.Controls
            MsgBox ctrl.Name
            'MsgBox ctrl.ControlType.TypeName
            MsgBox TypeName(ctrl)

            For Each prop In ctrl.Properties
                 If prop.Name = "RowSource" Then
                    MsgBox "stop it"
                 End If
                If (TypeName(ctrl) = "ComboBox" Or TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox") And (prop.Name = "RowSource" Or prop.Name = "ControlSource") Then
                    MsgBox prop.Value
                End If
            Next prop
        Next ctrl

        appAccess.DoCmd.Close acForm, frm.Name
    Next obj

    Set frm = Nothing
    appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
    Set appAccess = Nothing
End Sub
```